# How to deal with a friendly Boghog without hurting it, and maintaining a positive relationship?

Tags: fauna, communication, interspecies-relations

In the Hickhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy: Mostly Harmless, on the planet NowWhat there are the [Boghogs](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Boghog), and their way of communicating is to bite each other very hard on the thigh, so my question is, if I were to ever encounter one and I wanted to have some sort of friendship with it without either of us getting hurt too much, or without me having to hit it or something if it bit me in the thigh too hard, what would I do? Would I amour my thighs with special armour which would translate the bites into other electrical signals which I could understand without the pain? Or would there be an easier method without causing either of us too much damage?

Comment: You don your humor-proof trousers and hit them with your trusted anti-pun-gun. Like most animals that are bred for comic relief the common boghog loses it punch once the joke is removed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could wear some prosthetic legs, and try to make sure your actual legs are away from the Boghog's mouth (remember, the more legs you wear, the less probable it is that the Boghog bites one that is yours in a sensual sense). If you are a true hitchhiker, you should know how to make a false leg out of your towel.

In case the Boghog finally chooses to bit one of your fleshy legs, try to convince it to choose another one with the argument that such a leg is not actually yours, but you have borrowed it. Alternatively, explain that on such leg you are wearing one of your few socks without holes.

After the Boghog has finished biting your leg, remember that good manners mean that you have to reciprocate and bite furiously one of its legs.